# Fractions in chemical equations not working

Tags: equations, chemistry, split

I am trying to type a Boyles equation into my latex report and everything looks fine. This is how I usually code my equations:

```
\begin{gather}

n_{CH_4}=\frac{COD}{64\frac{g}{mol}}

\intertext{Where:}

\begin{tabular}

    $n_{CH_4}$ is the amount of molecular methane in $mol$\\

    $COD$ is experimentally obtained value 
of chemical oxygen demand

\end{tabular}\nonumber

\label{eq: n}

\end{gather}
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

For the Boyles equation I tried doing the same together with `\ch` command, but it became too long and ran off of my page. I tried many other options like `\split` or simply `\\` but nothing seemed to work. Now, I resorted to the following code:

```
$C_nH_aO_bN_c$+$(n-\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{2}+\frac{3c}{4})$ $H_2O$ \longrightarrow 
    ($\frac{n}{2}$+$\frac{a}{8}$-$\frac{b}{4}$-$\frac{3c}{8})$ $CH_4+(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4}+\frac{3c}{8})CO_2+cNH_3$
```

Fractions are still off, and I also don't have a numbering label next to my equation. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you considered employing a LaTeX package such as `mhchem` to help simplify and streamline the typing (and typsetting) of chemical formulas?

Comment: `\begin{tabular}` cannot possibly compile. Did you mean to write `\begin{tabular}{c}` (and also to delete all the blank lines inside the `gather` environment)?

Comment: @Mico the OP mentions `\ch` which is from the `chemformula` so they _did_ try a chemistry package but didn't succeed

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend that you employ a chemistry package, such as `mhchem`, to input and typeset chemical substances and equations. I'd also use the `\unit` and `\qty` macros of the siunitx package to express scientific units and quantities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}             % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % for '\ce' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}           % for 'multline*' environment
\usepackage{siunitx}           % for '\unit' and '\qty' macros

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{%  % 'p' col. type, w/ automatic hanging indentation
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{#1}}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}

\noindent
(bla bla bla \dots)
\[
 n_{\ce{CH4}}=\frac{\mathrm{COD}}{\qty{64}{\gram\per\mol}}
\]
where
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l P{3in} }
$n_{\ce{CH4}}$ & amount of molecular methane, in \unit{\mol} \\
$\mathrm{COD}$ & experimentally obtained value of chemical oxygen demand
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Using a \texttt{multline*} environment and six instances of \texttt{\string\ce}:
\begin{multline*}
\ce{C_nH_aO_bN_c} 
+ \Bigl(n-\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{2}+\frac{3c}{4}\Bigr) \ce{H2O} \\ 
\ce{->}
\Bigl(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{a}{8}-\frac{b}{4}-\frac{3c}{8}\Bigr) \ce{CH4}
+\Bigl(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4}+\frac{3c}{8}\Bigr)\ce{CO2}+c\ce{NH3}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely possible to have numbered reactions, e.g. using the [`chemmacros`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package. And if they're too long for one line I suggest to use more than one line.

What you shouldn't do is using math-mode for chemical formulas: they are not mathematical variables and really should be typeset upright. One should use [`chemformula`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) (the default in `chemmacros`) or [`mhchem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) for them.

Constructs like this

```
($\frac{n}{2}$+$\frac{a}{8}$-$\frac{b}{4}$-$\frac{3c}{8})$
```

are really wrong. You shouldn't leave math mode for plus and minus signs. Wrong spacing is just one of the erroneous consequences.

Here is a quick suggestion which also uses the [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for units and quantities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  reactions/own-counter = false % equations and reactions share counter
}
\NewChemReaction{multreaction}{multline}% new reaction type based on multline by amsmath

% setup siunitx (loaded by chemmacros)
\sisetup{
  per-mode = fraction
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for sample text

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  n_{\ch{CH4}}=\frac{COD}{\qty{64}{\gram\per\mole}}
\end{equation}
Where:
\begin{itemize}
  \item $n_{\ch{CH4}}$ is the amount of molecular methane in \unit{\mole}
  \item $COD$ is experimentally obtained value of chemical oxygen demand
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multreaction}
C_{$n$}H_{$a$}O_{$b$}N_{$c$} + $\Bigl(n-\frac{a}{4}-\frac{b}{2}+\frac{3c}{4}\Bigr)$ H2O -> \\
    $\Bigl(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{a}{8}-\frac{b}{4}-\frac{3c}{8}\Bigr)$ CH4 +
    $\Bigl(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4}+\frac{3c}{8}\Bigr)$ CO2 + $c$ NH3
\end{multreaction}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]